# Getting Cypress to run Headless Electron with Chrome DevTools Protocol

Tags: electron, cypress, chrome-devtools-protocol

Cypress version `^3.8.3`

Using Chrome I am able to setup and attached to the Remote Debugging Port.

In cypress/plugins/index.js

```js
  if (browser.name === "chrome") {            
    args.push("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
    return args;
  }
```

When starting a cypress run I can then prefix with the environment variable `CYPRESS_REMOTE_DEBUGGING_PORT=9222`.

However, when I try and do similar with Electron, I never get a connection.

```js
  if (browser.name === "electron") {
    args.webPreferences = {
      remoteDebuggingPort: 9222
    };
    //----OR------
    args.remoteDebuggingPort = 9222;
    return args;
  }
```

I feel like I'm missing something very simple! Any ideas on how to get Cypress Electron running the remote debug port, would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron does not listen for CDP messages on a port, the method you are trying to use is restricted to using CDP with standalone browsers for now.

---

However, if you just need to send CDP commands from your tests, and not subscribe to events, there is an **undocumented and unsupported** way to do that, via `Cypress.automation('remote:debugger:protocol', { command, params })`.

Example: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/d92d3c0bab21cbd4ff96c24848779461f183a6d6/packages/server/test/support/fixtures/projects/e2e/cypress/support/index.js#L1-L13